# Why group by and sum aren't removing dup values in rows

Tags: sql

We're using Netezza SQL.
I have three fields Customer, Account, and Revenue.

I'm summing the Revenue like so.

```
Select Customer, Sum(Revenue) REV_TOT
from Cust_REV
group by ACCOUNT;
```

Assuming there is more than one ACCOUNT PER CUST.

```
CUSTOMER    REV_TOT

15411780    0.5700

15411780    0.0000

15411790    65.1910

15411790    0.0000

15411790    21.4960

15411790    28.0180
```

Notice the CUSTOMER NUMBER Doesn't condense. Shouldn't it? What do I need to do?

Comment: Silly question, but you are grouping on "account" and displaying "customer".  Can a customer have more than 1 account?  If so, then this is normal - you are just not showing the relevant field.  Group on Customer in order to achieve what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Per the response from BlueGI, you are grouping on account and stating that the customer may have multiple accounts. Why would customer condense in this case? Assuming you only care about the output of Customer and Revenue you should be using the distinct keyword for customer... If you need to see each account as well then it should be included in the select statement and you can keep your original query.

```
Select Distinct(Customer), Sum(Revenue) REV_TOT
from Cust_REV
group by Customer;
```